# setState does not update state before function call in same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have an application using hooks using `state` and `setState` as variable names, hope that is not too confusing.  I try to call `setState(newState)`  and then run my `rotate()` function afterward when I check rotate it still has my `slots` empty. As if it did not update in time. Do I need to run this as a callback? Is `setState` not finished by the time `setState` is finished?

```
   const [ state, setState ] = useState({ manual: true, rings: [], slots: [] });
    const slotMap = {
      0: 288,
      1: 216,
      2: 144,
      3: 72,
      4: 360
  };

    useEffect(()=>{
      const newState = { ...state, slots: props.slots };
      console.log('DEGREES:');
      newState.slots.forEach(x => console.log(slotMap[x])); //works! 
      if(newState.slots !== undefined && props.apiHit === true ) {
        setState(newState);
        rotate();
      }

    }, [props.slots, props.apiHit]);

rotate =() => {
  console.log(state); 
}
```

output:

```
{manual: true, rings: Array(3), slots: Array(0)}manual: truerings: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]slots: Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

I definitely have `props.slots` having data. It just doesn't seem to populate when rotate is called. What am I missing in understanding about `setState`?

Comment: setting state is an assynchronous operation. Just call `console.log` in your component's body and you should see the correct updated value (in the next render)

Comment: or pass the updated state manually to your `rotate` function.

Comment: That's also a great ideia. Since you already knows the next state you can just pass it to rotate

Comment: yes that's what I was going to do was pass it as a parameter. I was just confused on `setState`'s behavior. Thank you all for letting me know!

Comment: @Dupocas can I use `async/wait` or use `.then()` with `setState`? or would this be bad practice?

Comment: @Dupocas The setter from useState is not asynchronous but since it doesn't mutate state you can see the changes only in the next render cycle so you have a stale closure.

Comment: In class based components `setState` takes an aditional argument which is a callback function to execute when all updates are done. But in functional components you don't even need that. The updated value will be available in the next render. Period

Comment: All state changes are assynchronous @HMR. Since react batches the updates in a qeue you can't really depend on the updated value at runtime. The next render in functional components is only triggered when the old and new state don't match anymore triggering the reconciliation. But the process of updating the internals of react still is async. So it may feel like sync, but in reality the new render is triggered by an async operation

Comment: @KyleCalica-St You can't use `await setState` because the setter from useState does not return a promise. Technically it **is** asynchronous since it can do batch updates but it's not asynchronous like fetch where you get a promise. I suggest just passing newState to rotate.

Comment: Exactly! Just pass the new state to rotate

Comment: wow this was a very helpful discussion thanks everyone!

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Another way to do it is: `const rotate = ()=>setState(state=>{console.log(state);return state;})` Because you are returning the same state it would not cause a re render. However; if you want to change `state` (or any other value created with useState) then passing newState to rotate will be best.